# vim keybindings with neo keyboard layout

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

This question is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165231/vim-dvorak-keybindings-rebindings), only regarding the (lesser known) [neo keyboard layout](http://neo-layout.org/) instead of dvorak.

I want to start programming and I understand that vi and vim are considered to be highly productive editors for coding if used wisely.
Now I'm using the neo keyboard layout and I wonder what keybindings for vim might be best suited for this layout.
I don't want to learn to use vim, find out my keybindings don't work well and then I have to readjust my habits.

So to all of you who use vim + neo: How do *you* remap vim's keybindings to best work with *neo*?

(More generally: What are the things I should keep in mind when changing vim keybindings?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, I wouldn't change the keybindings.  The Vim commands work because by and large they're mnemonics.  Just leave them alone and use them where they stand.  I see that hjkl aren't so well laid out on that layout but you do seem to have cursor keys behind "Ebene 4" so if that's not too much trouble maybe that'd be ok.  (I don't find myself using hjkl much anyway, I usually use other more direct jump movement commands.)

I'm a Dvorak layout user.

Comment: I’m going with this now.

Comment: Because of the cursor keys on level 4 you could even consider rebinding hjkl to other commands you tend to use often.  I am using neo layout und vim since about three years now, and never use hjkl for movement.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, as a **VIM user** but **not** a **Neo user**, I would generally mimic the VIM key layout onto your keyboard.  Pay attention to which keys in VIM are under the resting positions of each finger and translate that onto Neo.

Keeping a traditional layout that is overlaid onto new keyboard layout will keep common keys under your **resting finger positions**.  It will also build **muscle memory** that can be transferred to QWERTY when you need to work on a non-Neo keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I am a VIM and Neo2 User myself.
Both quite a time now. And I can tell you: about 90% of the commands are even nicer to use (imho at least), than they where back on qwertz. Some '`' commands type weird, but you get used to it. But you may consider to change vim's LEADER-Key (i've moved it to 'j') tho.